# PHP Multi-page Order Form

Tags: php, session, session-variables, typo3

This one has made me a lot of stress over the last couple of days. I am trying to set up a multi-page order form working with a CMS based on Typo3. However i am finding huge difficulties passing the session variables from a page to another. Session code is correct. I however suspect that i am not doing this accordingly to the CMS rulebook. So:

I have 4 pages in the order form. 4 .php files with 4 according .tpl files.

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php?puid=3&pageid=176">

    <input type="radio" name="rubrik" onchange="toggleDiv('show',0);toggleDiv('check',0)" value="kfz" />KFZ

    <br></br>
    <input name="rubrik" id="immo" onchange="toggleDiv('show',1);toggleDiv('check',1)" type="radio" value="immobilien" class="static" />Immobilien
        <input type="image" action="/index.php?puid=3&pageid=176" value="submit" src="/images/weiter.png" alt="Submit" style="float:right; margin-right:275px; margin-bottom:50px; margin-bottom:50px; margin-left:25px; text-align:left;" ></input>
</form>
```

This is my first form. In page1.tpl. page2.php starts like this:

```
<?php   

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Rubrik wahl'] = 'rubrik';

    if (isset($_POST['rubrik'])){
    $_SESSION['rubrik']=$_POST['rubrik'];
    }
```

While in page.tpl i have:

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php?puid=3&pageid=177">
            <textarea name="inhalt1" cols="40" rows="8" style="width:618px; height:200px;" onKeyDown="textCounter(document.inhalt.inhalt1,document.inhalt.counter,180)" onKeyUp="textCounter(document.inhalt.inhalt1,document.inhalt.counter,180)" ></textarea> 
            <input type="hidden" name="rubrik" value="<?php echo 'rubrik';?>"></input>  
    <br></br><br></br><br></br>     
    <input type="image" action="/index.php?puid=3&pageid=177" value="submit" src="/images/weiter.png" alt="Submit" style="margin-bottom:50px; margin-left:25px; text-align:left; float:right; margin-right:275px; margin-bottom:50px;"></input>

            </form>
```

Now why does the 'rubrik' variable not pass from one page to another?

Comment: If you're calling your own page (`page2.php`), the problem you describe is outside the scope of TYPO3. It also looks like you're using your own variables for pages (`puid` and `pageid`). How do you include the PHP files in TYPO3?

Comment: The company that produced the CMS, called redFACT, has just told me it is not possbile to run sessions on the page because it is static. Is that possible?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. If you bypass the TYPO3 API, then you run in this kind of problems. Normally TYPO3 content is cached and you must tell TYPO3 about possible parameters, so TYPO3 can take care to store a different version in the cache for each parameter combination. Also as already mentioned, you are not using the normal get parameters (id for site and what is puid?). Unless you tell us what you actually want to archive and "what the hell" you are currently doing, then we might be able to help you. There are multiple form extension which allow you to set up forms without PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. You are not doing it the way, you should do with TYPO3.

But i guess, you are just not using TYPO3 anyway. redFact is an commercial CMS build by the web agency [newsagency](http://www.newsfactory.de/).  [TYPO3](http://www.typo3.org) is a opensource CMS itself, it is build by an [active community](http://typo3.org/development/), but not by an single company.

So, at first check, if you are using TYPO3, if so buy an book or have a look at some extensions in [TER](http://typo3.org/extensions/) and the [API](http://api.typo3.org).

Have a look at [$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classtslib__fe_user_auth.html#a559c1b10ba58f6f05094a1f2c3afee3b), setKey and $GLOBALS['TSFE']->[storeSessionData](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classtslib__fe_user_auth.html#ae22e576b8a950c929246e7e653875d1c)()

I guess, you are able to read german (your button is called "weiter"). So there are a lot of german TYPO3 books. Just buy some of them and start using the API. I know one pretty good book in english "Typo3 Extension Development" by Dmitry Dulepov, even it is from 2008, it is still valid for beginners.

Comment: redFACT is actually a CMS based on Typo3. It's bassicaly Typo3 with heavy modifications. So most of the rules that apply for Typo3 are out of the question. However it allows you to define certain parameters outside the predefined classes. But i don't understand why it isn't allowing to start and run sessions within the .php files.

Comment: If you can, install extension kickstarter and write an plugin.